# Projective complex variety of degree $3$ and codimension $2$ (Mumford's Complex Projective Varieties)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X^{n-2} \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ a complex projective $n-2$-dimensional variety
of degree $3$. Assume that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the *smallest* linear space containing $X$. That means it's not possible to find a proper linear subspace $L^k \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ containing $X$.

How it can be shown that $X$ is defined by the vanishing set of the three
$2 \times 2$ minors of a linear $3 \times 2$ matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$a_i, b_i$ are linear forms in $X_0,..., X_n$.

Could somebody explain why is this the case?
Source: David Mumford's Algebraic geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties page 80.

What I know. Degree $3$ assumption imply that there exist a general $2$-dimensional
$\mathbb{P}^2 \cong L^2 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ with $X \cap L = \{y^1, y^2, y^3\}$.
After a well chosen $PGL(n)$ transformation of $\mathbb{P}^n$ we can assume
$L^2= V(X_3, X_4,..., X_n)$. Additionally assume that the points $y^1, y^2, y^3$
are contained in affine part $D(X_2) \cong \mathbb{A}^2 \subset L^2$; equivalently
for $ V(X_2, X_3,..., X_n) = L^2 \cap V(X_2) \cong \mathbb{P}^1 $ the intersection
with $X$ is empty.

If we denote $y^i= (y^i_0: y^i_1: 1: y^i_2,..., y^i_n)$ (that's possible
since $y_i \not \in V(X_2)$) then in $\mathbb{A}^2$ we can write down the intersection
$X \cap L^2$ as
algebraic set

$$V( (X_0- y_0^{a}) \cdot (X_1 - y_1^{b} \ \vert \ a, b \in \{1,2,3\}, a \neq b )$$

Can we derive from that the structure of vanishing polynomials for $X$.

Comment: I'm curious about the answer to this. I don't have time right now to do so, but I would suggest looking in Dolgachev's book/notes Classical Algebraic Geometry from a Modern Viewpoint (or something like that). That book's raison d'etre is explicating these kinds of classical structure theorems and rephrasing them in modern language.

Comment: See "On Varieties of Minimal Degree (A Centennial Account)" by Eisenbud and Harris, available online. Your varieties are one case of _varieities of minimal degree_: such a variety (unless it is the Veronese surface in $\mathbf P^5$) must be a scroll, and the ideal of a scroll of degree 3 and codimension 2 is of the given form.